# Temperamental behavior with submitting a form

Tags: javascript, html, parse-server

Hi (i'm new to this so you'll need to forgive me)

My end goal is to create a form that will submit some data to a back-end database called parse server. So far I've created everything i need and it seems to be partially working however i'm experiencing some rather weird behavior. If i attempt to submit the form as expected it appears to do nothing (no data is saved to the database).

After some testing i have concluded that the code will only run as expected when i do the following:

1. Submit the form completely blank.
2. Enter the data in as normal and submit again (works as expected).

If i attempt to submit the form a third time after entering in the data as normal it appears to do nothing.

I'm at a loss given the results seem to be temperamental. I have checked the debugging console to see if that may give me any clues however no errors are received.

Is anyone aware of what might be causing this strange behavior?

(I've obscured the relevant parse access keys).

**Affected HTML code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/parse_functions.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://npmcdn.com/parse@1.8.5/dist/parse-latest.js"></script>
  </head>   
  <body>
<header>
    <div class="jumbotron" style="background:#006272 !important">
        <div class="container">
            <center><img src="logo.png" width="450px" height="93px"/></center><br/>
            <center><h2 style="color:#ffffff">[ALPHA] Mobile App Dashboard</h2></center>
        </div> 
    </div> 
</header>

<div class="container">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
        <li class="active"><a href="#Home" data-toggle="tab">Absences</a></li>
        <li><a href="#About" data-toggle="tab">Push Notifications</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane fade in active"  id="Home" style="padding-top:30px">

            <form class="form-horizontal">
            <fieldset>

            <!-- Text input-->
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="teacherName">Teacher name</label>  
              <div class="col-md-4">
              <input id="teacherName" type="text" placeholder="e.g. Mr Smith" class="form-control input-md" required="">

              </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Textarea -->
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="workDescription">Work Description</label>
              <div class="col-md-4">                     
                <textarea id="workDescription" class="form-control" name="workDescription"></textarea>
              </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Text input-->
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="linkLocation">Work Link</label>  
              <div class="col-md-4">
              <input id="linkLocation" type="text" placeholder="e.g. http://www.google.co.uk/" class="form-control" required="">

              </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Button -->
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="absence"></label>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <button id="absence" name="absence" class="btn btn-success" onClick="saveData()">Submit Absence</button>
              </div>
            </div>

            </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade"  id="About" style="padding-top:30px">
            <form class="form-horizontal">
            <fieldset>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="notificationTitle">Notification Title</label>  
              <div class="col-md-4">
              <input id="notificationTitle" name="notificationTitle" type="text" placeholder="e.g. Mr Smith" class="form-control input-md" required="">

              </div>
            </div>


            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="workDescription">Notification Message</label>
              <div class="col-md-4">                     
                <textarea id="workDescription" class="form-control" id="workDescription" name="workDescription"></textarea>
              </div>
            </div>



            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="absence"></label>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <button id="absence" name="absence" class="btn btn-success" onClick="saveData()">Send Notification</button>
              </div>
            </div>

            </fieldset>
            </form> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**Affected Javascript code:**

```
    function saveData(){
    // initializes the connection to parse with the parameters (appId, javascript key)
    Parse.initialize("##########################", "##########################");
    Parse.serverURL = 'https://parseapi.back4app.com/'

    var absence = Parse.Object.extend("Absences");
    var absence = new absence();

    var name = document.getElementById('teacherName').value
    var description = document.getElementById('workDescription').value
    var link = document.getElementById('linkLocation').value

    absence.set("name", name);
    absence.set("work", description);
    absence.set("link", link);

    alert("test");

    absence.save(null, {
      success: function(gameScore) {
        // Execute any logic that should take place after the object is saved.
        alert("Created!");
      },
      error: function(gameScore, error) {
        // Execute any logic that should take place if the save fails.
        // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and message.
        alert('Failed to create new object, with error code: ' + error.message);
      }

});
}
```

I've also made a simplified version of my code to try and debug it - this version works fine and produces the expected result yet still uses the same javascript:

```
    <!doctype html>

    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">

      <title>Data insert test</title>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://npmcdn.com/parse@1.8.5/dist/parse-latest.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>

    <input placeholder="Teacher Name" id="teacherName"/>
    <br/>   
    <input placeholder="Work Description" id="workDescription"/>
    <br/>   
    <input placeholder="Work link/location" id="linkLocation"/>
    <br/>
    <button type="button" onclick="saveData()">Save Data</button>



    <script type="text/javascript">


    function saveData(){
        // initializes the connection to parse with the parameters (appId, javascript key)
        Parse.initialize("##########################", "##########################");
        Parse.serverURL = 'https://parseapi.back4app.com/'

        var absence = Parse.Object.extend("Absences");
        var absence = new absence();

        var name = document.getElementById('teacherName').value
        var description = document.getElementById('workDescription').value
        var link = document.getElementById('linkLocation').value

        absence.set("name", name);
        absence.set("work", description);
        absence.set("link", link);

        absence.save(null, {
          success: function(gameScore) {
            // Execute any logic that should take place after the object is saved.
            alert('New object created with objectId: ' + absense.id);
          },
          error: function(gameScore, error) {
            // Execute any logic that should take place if the save fails.
            // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and message.
            alert('Failed to create new object, with error code: ' + error.message);
          }

    });
    }



  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You might be new at this, but you've done a good job laying our your problem and code. +1 for that.

Comment: I may be mistaken, but it looks like you only specified the button 'type' in your second example.  Can you try setting "type=button" in the first example?  If your browser is assuming submit as your default, this could be the root cause.

Comment: One thing I noticed - ``Parse.initialize`` likely needs to be run just once, currently you're re-initializing on each submission.  And just to clarify - after you load the page, enter your data and hit submit, it does not submit as expected?  You have to submit it blank first?

Comment: Ah it seems to be exactly that (hadn't set `type="button"`)! I knew it was probably something trivial - thank you so much! Your also right in saying `Parse.initialize` doesn't need to be run twice - I've adapted the code.